# Holes in blank 4-gang wall plate don’t line up

Tags: electrical, receptacle

For some reason there are two 2-gang outlets right next to each other in my child’s bedroom.  I wanted to clean up the way the wall looks (there are also a couple media and telecommunications outlets) so I got a blank wall plate to cover one of the two-gangs up, but its screw holes do not align with the existing screws on the receptacles.  The holes are positioned roughly with the middle of each outlet.  Are there blank 2-gang plates with just two holes, each aligning with the center of each receptacle? Am I not supposed to be covering the receptacles with a blank?

Comment: Pictures would help a **lot**.

Comment: Knowing the country might also help... Blank plates I've seen are usually used to close off boxes that do _not_ have outlets or switches currently installed in them. What's your actual goal here? If childproofing, you want to replace any remaining outlets with child-resistant ones, and it might be simpler to just do that across the whole set rather than covering.

Comment: "two 4-gang outlets"? Are you sure? That's a total of 8 "gangs" which, if they have standard duplex receptacles installed, gives you a total of 16 outlets ... That seems more than a little unlikely. Please [Edit] your question and add some pics for us to be able to see what you see.

Comment: Thanks, I’ve updated my goal for clarity.  Agreed, pictures would’ve been helpful initially—I have sufficient feedback at this point however.  Thanks for pointing out the incorrect terminology.  In fact, I am referring to 2-gangs, not 4-gangs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question as written, NO...you cannot cover an outlet with a blank cover.  Blank covers are made to cover boxes that do not have outlets or switches in them.

If your goal is to childproof the outlets in the room, there are many products that can be used to make the outlets and the switches very difficult for children to "play" with. ( usually a type of cover)  Google "Child electrical safety"
Or look in the "infant/ baby" departments of most any store.

Comment: Good to know about not covering the outlet.  The goal is to clean it up visually, not to make it safer.  My son is 10.  Ideally, I would retire the outlet and remove the receptacle, but it is more than I have time for at the moment.  
Thanks for your comments.

Comment: @Loutro Many outlets are mandatory.  You can't just remove those. They don't need to be 4-gang, but they do need to be *there*.  In particular in most rooms, you must be able to place a lamp *anywhere* along the wall with its 6 foot cord being able to reach an outlet.  The next homeowner may not have bookshelves or whatever there.

Comment: There are two 2-gangs next to each other.  Removing one of them would not create a compliance issue as far as outlet spacing is concerned.